# Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map<Id,Candidate__c> at line 27 column 30

Tags: trigger

I am trying to update parent field value to a child fields. when parent field deleted child values shouldn't be deleted. Please help me for the following.

```
trigger updateallJobapplicationfields on Candidate__c (after update) {

    Map<Id, Candidate__c> changed = new Map<Id, Candidate__c>();

    Candidate__c old;

    for(Candidate__c cands: trigger.new){

     old= trigger.oldmap.get(cands.id);

    if(cands.JOb_Application_details__c != old.JOb_Application_details__c){

    changed.put(cands.id,cands);
    }
   }

   if(Changed.size >0){

   List<Job_Application__c > updates= new List<Job_Application__c >();

   for(Job_Application__c  jobs: [select  id,name,Cover_Letter__c from Job_Application__c where Candidate__c in: changed.keyset()]){

       Candidate__c cands = changed.get(jobs.Candidate__c);

       if(jobs.Cover_Letter__c !='' && changed.JOb_Application_details__c !='' ){

       jobs.Cover_Letter__c= changed.JOb_Application_details__c;
      // jobs.Cover_Letter__c = changed.put(changed.id,changed.JOb_Application_details__c);


       updates.add(jobs);

       }
       update updates;


   }
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Eric's answer already pointed out your issue. But since you still look confused. Here is the updated code from Line 23 - 31.

```
   Candidate__c cands = changed.get(jobs.Candidate__c);

   if(cands != null && cands.JOb_Application_details__c != null && cands.JOb_Application_details__c != ''){

     jobs.Cover_Letter__c= changed.JOb_Application_details__c;

     updates.add(jobs);
   }
```

In short, for a particular candidate, you should be using the variable cands, instead of changed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since `changed` is a map, you need to get the value using the `get` method and the key to return the Candidate__c.

So everywhere you are using `changed.` you should be doing a `changed.get(key)` and it will return the value for that key from the map.

You code is not easy to understand due to all of the issues but this is the cause of the error in your question

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your reply, It didn't work for me.  Ideally my logic is for whenever parent field value is updated corresponding all child field value should be update,however parent value is deleted then child field value shoudn't be erased.Thank you

Comment: If you have any other simpler logic, you can provide me,much appreciated Thanks